# How to specify which app to make changes with heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

Hello I have multiple heroku apps. Whenever I I run this command heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs  it applies it to the wrong heroku app. How can I specify which app to make this change to. It seems like whenever I run any command with heroku it does it to a different app.

Answer (score 0):

Most Heroku CLI commands support the `-a` parameter to specify the application, in this case:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs -a <app name>
```

Comment: This worked good for that. Problem is whenever I push using git push heroku main it pushed to a unwanted repository.

Comment: You can try to change the remote for your repo with `heroku git:remote -a myapp` or recreate the app and repo, something must have gone wrong